# How do I report ATM card abuse?

Tags: atm

My ATM Card was taken by a friend and transferred all my money to another bank as fundraising.
How can I get the details of the bank the money was transferred to?

[image] [image]

Comment: If you didn't authorize this, then contact your bank and the police.

Comment: _You_ almost certainly can't get the details, but the bank/police probably can if you follow mhoran's advice and let them know.

Answer (score 8):

As the comments said: take this to your bank and the police. Report it as a stolen ATM card.

If the transfer was electronic, the bank may be able to reverse it; stolen cards are not rare. If it was in cash, the bank may have video they can give the police to help prove what happened.

This person is not your friend. Or they were desperate and need help that you can't give them. Either way, it's a police matter.